# Top property on fixed element effecting inner absolute positioned elements

Tags: html, css

I have created a burger icon for my nav bar. The outer container is fixed with the inner bars positioned absolute. The problem is that when I apply the top property to the outer fixed element it effects the height of the bars inside. Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Here's a little demo that I created:

```css
div{
    position: fixed;
    /*top: 3.4em;  /*uncomment this to see the problem*/ 
    right: 5em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 50;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 0.063em solid #ff6633;
    border-radius: 0.313em;
}

span{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0.2em;
    width: 1.5em;
    background-color: #ff6633;
    left: 0.25em;
}

span:nth-child(1){
  top: 0.25em;
}

span:nth-child(2){
  top: 0.863em;
}

span:nth-child(3){
  top: 1.438em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ezp43625/

Comment: It is working properly

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting the top property to see the problem?

Comment: Try to do in `pixels`

Comment: I had the same problem with pixels

Comment: It seems ok when you change in inspect

Comment: Why you need to use ems? The problem is because everything is rounding to the nearest pixel, so just use whole number pixels?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a browser rendering issue. If you zoom in or inspect the height, it show the same height for three lines. So may be you can try changing the top offset. For me it look good with

```
top: 3.5em
```

Comment: Yes I noticed that it worked fine with different top properties. But its rather annoying on my website as it wont allow me to properly center the bars